# Connecting to remote Oracle server through shell script

Tags: shell, unix, oracle10g, oracle11g

i am new to shell script. i have a Oracle server which is remote say "Oracle1" and listening to port 1521 i am trying to remotely connect to it through shell script. i am facing some issue in setting environment variables. my script is.

```
ORACLE_SID=wctest98;
export ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_HOME=Oracle1.com:1521/opt/oracle/oracle11g/product/11.2.0;
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH;
export PATH
SQLPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin;
export SQLPATH

sqlplus -s /NOLOG << EOF
connect wcadmin/wcadmin@Oracle1.com:1521/wctest98
select * from dual;
exit

EOF
```

i am getting "**sqlplus:  not found**" error. i am doing it for the first time. i have connected to local Oracle System but not to remote server. feel free to edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ORACLE_HOME` (below) looks incorrect to me. It should not contain the host and port of your oracle server.

```
ORACLE_HOME=Oracle1.com:1521/opt/oracle/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/bin;
```

ORACLE_HOME is the path to wherever you have installed the Oracle client on the local machine. For example, it might be:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/oracle11g/product/11.2.0
```

Check if you have the `sqplus` executable in `${ORACLE_HOME}/bin`.

Comment: well i have a doubt on the way i am setting the ORACLE_HOME for remote server. is it the right way to set environment variable for remote server. i made the changes as you mentioned but its still the same error.

Comment: No, `ORACLE_HOME` is where you have installed Oracle Client on the LOCAL machine.

Comment: well i have posted a new script below and also a screen shot my server folder structure depending upon that i have made the necessary changes.

Comment: Does `/opt/oracle/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus` exist on the machine where you are running this script?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like sqlplus is not on your PATH variable.

You can see if it is with

```
which sqlplus
```

And find where it is with

```
locate sqlplus
```

To add something to your path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/sqlplusdir/
```